# How to read Data from File in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, filereader

"Reading the data from the `File` using `Java` code without any errors and no limitations".
Using the `files` concept to get the data from the file into the program, the code is given below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the code to read data from file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Demo17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        File f1 = new File("E:\\usersData.txt"); //getting the file path
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);  // reading the file data
        char[] cArr = new char[(int) f1.length()];  // Creating an character array
        fr.read(cArr); // Reading the character array
        String s1 = new String(cArr); // converting to string array
        System.out.println("Data present in File is : "+s1);
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post example code as an answer to your question, that's not what it is... This should be part of the question along with a real question (as far as I can see, you did not formulate a question). Could you please put this code into your question and delete this "answer"?

Comment: Did you  really just provide an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [Reader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) from official Java documentation.
Having that out of the way, if you want to read raw data, I would suggest using [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), whereas, for text files, I would definitely check out [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).

Here is an example code:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");

try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file))
{
    int content;
    while ((content = fr.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) content);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Alternatively you can quickly read all lines of a File with:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("file.txt"));
```

Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: You only compare which code is easy to understand Mr @Timino